# The following sentence is correct in terms of grammar?

Tags: inversion, neither-nor, compound-complex

What I'm trying to say - [I'm not studying or working at the moment]

The sentence that I like to use - I'm not studying nor am I working at the moment.

Comment: Why do you prefer your suggested alternant?

Comment: What is your doubt about this sentence.  It's fine.  Why do you think there is a problem?

Comment: Put a comma before "nor" since it is a coordinating conjunction introducing a coordinate clause, unlike the prior sentence since what follows the coordinating conjunction "or" in that prior sentence isn't a coordinate clause as it refers back to the subject-verb "I'm" at the start of the sentence.